# How to know if my react native expo app is using External GPS readings?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, expo, gps, react-native-maps

I've built an expo app using expo location and react native maps libraries. I connect an external GPS via Bluetooth to my phone. Then the accuracy reading in my app becomes fixed at 5 meters. I don't know if my app is using the readings from external gps or internal gps (phone's gps). Is there a way to get readings from external gps into my app?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the sampling rate. Which phone? iPhone is 1hz I believe.